# How to set a parameter of function based on number of rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I don't know how to set the second parameter of the `setRowHeightsForced` function to be based on number of rows

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('A4:EP').activate();
spreadsheet.getRange('3:3').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
spreadsheet.getRange('A3:A').setValue('TRUE');
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()\[0\];
sheet.setRowHeightsForced(3,4,27);
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
```

I want that `4` on second-to-last line to be based on the current total number of rows, since it keeps changing every time a new response is received (google forms).

Also I would like something similar on the second line. That `A4:EP` would work better if it was something like `A4:Infinite`, since sometimes I have to add columns.

Comment: I have corrected a badly-formatted question. Please review your code and update it in case there are other syntax errors created by additional characters you added in your attempts to format it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess something like this:

```
setRowHeightsForced(sr, sheet.getLastRow() - sr + 1, height)
```